# Combination of Poisson and binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm working on the following problem

> Each time you flip a certain coin, heads appears with probability $p$. Suppose that you flip the coin a random number of $N$ times, where $N$ has the Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$ and is independent of the outcomes of the flips. Find the distributions of the numbers $X$ and $Y$ of the resulting heads and tails, respectively, and show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

What I tried, is conditioning on the value of $N$:
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}(X=x) & = & \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X=x \ | \  N=k)\mathbb{P}(N=k)\\
& = & \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{k}{x}p^x(1-p)^{k-x}\frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}\\
& = & \sum_{k=x}^{\infty}\binom{k}{x}p^x(1-p)^{k-x}\frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}.\\
\end{eqnarray}
Similarly, for $Y$ i found $$\mathbb{P}(y=y)=\sum_{k=y}^{\infty}\binom{k}{y}p^{k-y}(1-p)^y\frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}.$$
I tried to work this out but I didn't seem to go anywhere. The answer should be that $X \sim Pois(\lambda p)$ and because of symmetry we would have $Y \sim Pois(\lambda (1-p))$.

Can anyone provide some help about how to from where I came to $X \sim Pois(\lambda p)$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the way, I know how to show $X$ and $Y$ are independent given $X \sim Pois(\lambda p)$ and $X \sim Pois(\lambda (1-p))$ so it's not necessary to answer that subquestion.

Comment: Why do you need to multiply with ℙ(=)? Isn't it enough that  ℙ(= | =)? What property are you using?

Comment: @TheEconomist https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/176930/321264

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to use [moment-generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) (MGF): simpler, faster proof. Namely, you have, for $t\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} e^{tX}
&= \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}[ e^{tX} \mid N ] ]
\stackrel{(\dagger)}{=} \mathbb{E}[ (1-p+pe^{t})^N ]\\
&= \mathbb{E}[ e^{N\ln(1-p+pe^{t})} ]
\stackrel{(\ddagger)}{=} \exp(\lambda(e^{\ln(1-p+pe^{t})}-1))\\
&= \exp(\lambda((1-p+pe^{t})-1))\\
&= \exp(\lambda p(e^{t}-1))
\end{align}$$
where $(\dagger)$ uses the expression of the MGF of a [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with parameters $N$ and $p$, and $(\ddagger)$ that of the MGF of a [Poisson  distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) with parameter $\lambda$ (applied to the argument $t'\stackrel{\rm def}{=}\ln(1-p+pe^{t})$).

At the end, you get that, for every $t\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
\mathbb{E} e^{tX} = \exp(\lambda p(e^{t}-1)) \tag{$\ast$}
$$ 
which is the MGF of a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda p$. As [the MGF characterizes the distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Important_properties) (when it exists), we have the result.

---

However, if you want to finish your computation: here how it goes. I assume $p\neq 1$, otherwise the answer is trivial.
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\{X=n\} &= \sum_{k=n}^\infty \binom{k}{n}p^n(1-p)^{k-n} \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}\\
&= e^{-\lambda}\frac{p^n}{(1-p)^n}\sum_{k=n}^\infty \binom{k}{n}(1-p)^{k} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}\\
&= e^{-\lambda}\frac{p^n}{(1-p)^n}\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{k!}{n!(k-n)!}(1-p)^{k} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}\\
&= e^{-\lambda}\frac{p^n}{n!(1-p)^n}\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{(k-n)!}(1-p)^{k} \lambda^k\\
&= e^{-\lambda}\frac{p^n}{n!(1-p)^n}\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\ell!}(1-p)^{\ell+n} \lambda^{\ell+n}\\
&= e^{-\lambda}\frac{(\lambda p)^n}{n!}\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \frac{(1-p)^{\ell} \lambda^{\ell}}{\ell!}\\
&= e^{-\lambda}\frac{(\lambda p)^n}{n!}e^{\lambda(1-p)}
= \boxed{e^{-\lambda p}\frac{(\lambda p)^n}{n!}}
\end{align}
and you get the probability mass function of a Poisson r.v. with parameter $\lambda p$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I have never seen moment-generating functions before. Would you know a more elementary approach?

Comment: Yes. I can update my answer to show how to finish your computation.

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov Updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, I forgot to substitute the Taylor series expansion for $e^x$ but now i understand!

Comment: What you call the MGF is usually referred to as the characteristic function being related to the MGF by $\phi_X(t)=M_X(it)$, where $\phi$ is the CF and $M$ the MGF (of some RV). Or perhaps it was a typo, as you start out with $E(e^{itX})$ but end with the expression for the MGF—without any $i$.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 I know what the CF is, and its relation to the MGF. I used the MGF for simplicity here, to avoid taking the N-power of a complex number. It'd have made things less nice.

Comment: @ClementC. Right. Then why start off with $E(e^{itX})$?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 Typo. There should have been no $i$. Fixed, thanks!