# Poisson Distribution. Probability k eggs laid given that n insects developed

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

Let $X$ denotes the Number of eggs; poisson-distributed with parameter $\lambda$. Each egg hatches independently of the other eggs with probability $p$. 
$Y$ denotes the number of the "developed" insects.

What's the probability that $k$ eggs laid given that $n$ insects developed ? 
Obviously we have to use the formula of conditional-probability.

So I think that we have to start with:
$$ P( X=k | Y=n ) = \frac{P( {X=k} \cap {Y=n} )}{P ( Y = n )} $$ But I'm not sure. I know that $P$( $X$ = $k$ ) = $e^{-\lambda}$ $\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$.

Comment: The distribution of $Y$, conditional on $X=k$, should be well known to you.

Comment: I think Y is then binomial distributed. So $$ P( Y=n | X=k ) =  {k \choose n} \dot p^n \dot (1-p)^{k-n} $$  Could I use:  P(A|B) * $\frac{P(B)}{P(A)}$ = P(B|A) or am I wrong? Does this equality even hold?

Comment: Yes.  $P(A|B)P(B)=P(AB)=P(B|A)P(A)$ so as long as $P(A)\ne0$ you are safe.

Comment: I try this exercise on my own. Can you check my solution, please?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2507946/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/176930/321264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we know that: $$ P( Y=n | X=k ) =  {k \choose n} * p^n * (1-p)^{k-n} $$ We also know:  $$ P (X = k) = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} $$ Moreover we know: $$ P(Y=n) = e^{-\lambda*p} \frac{(p*\lambda)^n}{n!} $$ We begin with: $$ P( X=k | Y=n ) = \frac{P( {X=k} \cap {Y=n} )}{P ( Y = n )} = \frac{P( Y=n | X=k )* P(X=k)}{P(Y=n)} $$ Now we use the equalities ( above ) : We get : $$ P( X=k | Y=n ) =  e^{-\lambda(1-p)} * \frac{ (\lambda * ( 1 - p ))^{k-n}}{(k-n)!} $$ Am I right or where is my mistake? Is this the probability?

Comment: You have a tiny mistake at the end of the calculation.  Where you have $e^{-p}$ you should have $e^{-\lambda(1-p)}$.  Otherwise it looks OK to me. As a check you should verify that $\sum_k P(X=k|Y=n) = 1$.  Part of this check is figuring out what the possible $k$ values are.

Comment: found my mistake. You're right. Thank you.