# Random variables depending on a Poisson variable

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, random-variables, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

Consider a Bernoulli experiment of parameter $p$ that can be repeated independently for $N$ times, where $N \sim $ Poisson$(\lambda)$. Let $X$ be the number of successes and $Y$ the number of failures. How can I calculate the distribution of $X$ and $Y$? My attempt with $X$ was to consider it as a Binomial with parameters $N,p$ (and $Y$ can be considered as a Binomial with parameters $N,1-p$). The only thing that came out in my mind was to use the disintegration formula as it follows:
$$P(X=k)=\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}P(X=k \mid N=n)P(N=n)=\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\dfrac{\lambda ^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda}=\\
=\dfrac{p^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\dfrac{(1-p)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\lambda^n$$
Is this correct? And if it is, how do I evaluate the last series (Wolphram Alpha says $\lambda^ke^{\lambda-\lambda p}$)?

Comment: Hint: $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$

Comment: Yes, this is what I was thinking about $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\frac{(1-p)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1-p)^n}{n!}=e^{1-p}$, but that $\lambda ^n$ is bothering me

Comment: Variants of this question has been asked many a time, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2507946/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/176930/321264. Please search the site.

Comment: $\sum\limits_{n=k}^\infty \cfrac{(1-p)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!} \lambda^n = \lambda^k \sum\limits_{n=k}^\infty \cfrac{(1-p)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!} \lambda^{n-k} = \lambda ^k \sum\limits_{n=k}^\infty \cfrac{(\lambda-\lambda p)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}$

Comment: @StubbornAtom I searched for that but I hadn't found anything. I didn't know that someone did the same question, sorry about that. Do I have to delete the question?

Comment: You may want to explore the use of characteristic function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution